# Get how many pixels do the Viewholder (RecyclerView) moved when swiped

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, position, pixel

Hello i am using a recyclerView  and i am wanting to know if there exist any way to
get the pixel position of the row Viewholder beign swiped.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From `ItemTouchHelper.Callback` override `onChildDraw` as it gives all info you need , or use a helper like [this](https://github.com/sarafanshul/Habbit/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/projectdelta/habbit/widget/adapter/CustomItemTouchHelperCallback.java) and see usage [here](https://github.com/sarafanshul/Habbit/blob/8aa5f22c41492b5823066c19550c40287dfbfa80/app/src/main/java/com/projectdelta/habbit/ui/main/fragment/TodoFragment.kt#L131)

Comment: what i found is that i can get the x position while i pressing, but is there any way to get the x position of the cell when i am not pressing?

Comment: No , I can't think of anything like that .